# For arbitrary $\{X_n\}$ if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ \mathbb{E}(|{X_n}|)} <\infty$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ {X_n}} $ converges absolutely $a.e$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

For arbitrary  $\{X_n\}$ if
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ \mathbb{E}(|{X_n}|)} <\infty$$

then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ {X_n}} $ converges absolutely $a.e$

**MY SOLUTION:** For Three series of Kolmogorov,

**Series 1** We must verify that $\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|X_n| > 1) < +\infty$. Observe
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > 1) &\le& \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E} (|X_n|)  < \infty.\\
\end{eqnarray}
thus series 1 ok.

**Series 2** We need to show $\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|X_n| 1_{|X_n|\le 1})$ converges. by the hypothesis we have.
$$
\ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|X_n| 1_{|X_n|\le 1}) \le  \sum_{n\le 1}^{}{ \mathbb{E}(|{X_n}|)} <\infty.
$$
thus series 2 ok.

**Series 3** We must show $\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathrm{Var}(|X_n| 1_{|X_n|\le 1}) < \infty$. Given $(*)$ above, this is easy:
\begin{eqnarray}
(*)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathrm{Var}(|X_n| 1_{|X_n|\le 1}) &\le& \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|X_n|^2 1_{|X_n|\le 1}) < \infty.
\end{eqnarray}

$(*)\,\,$ why this$\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}(|X_n|^2 1_{|X_n|\le 1})$ series converges?

I do not know, thanks for your help.

Comment: $|X_{n}|^{2}1_{|X_{n}|\leq 1} \leq |X_{n}|1_{|X_{n}|\leq 1} \leq |X_{n}|$

Comment: it is true,  was a mere detail thanks ^^,

Answer (score 3):

It's much simpler than that.

Just note by the Monotone Convergence Theorem that $$\Bbb E\bigg[ \sum_n |X_n|\bigg] = \sum_n \Bbb E[|X_n|]$$

and one side is finite iff the other is. Hence it follows that $\Bbb E \big[ \sum_n |X_n| \big]<\infty$.

But if $Y$ is any nonnegative random variable such that $\Bbb E[Y] < \infty$ then it must follow that $Y< \infty$ almost surely. Applying this to $Y=\sum_n |X_n|$, we see that $\sum_n |X_n|<\infty$ almost surely, i.e. the series for $|X_n|$ converges absolutely a.s.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ \mathbb{E}(|{X_n}|)} <\infty$$

$$\to \mathbb{E} \left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ |{X_n}|} \right] <\infty \tag{1}$$

$$\to \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{ |{X_n}|} <\infty \ \text{a.e./a.s.} \ \tag{2}$$

$(1)$

$$E[\sum_n X_n] = \sum_n E[X_n] \ \text{if} \ X_n \ge 0$$

$(2)$

$$X = \infty \ \text{a.s./a.e.} \ \to E[X] = \infty$$